# How to define JuMP variables using for loop in Julia?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

I am new to Julia, and I am trying to define an optimization problem with [JuMP](https://github.com/JuliaOpt/JuMP.jl). I have a lot of variables (`x1,x2,x3....`) that I am trying to define using a `for` loop. I want to have the code:

```
@variable(m, x1>=0)
@variable(m, x2>=0) ...
```

However I wanted to use a `for` loop so I did not have to define every variable manually.
Here is what I have so far:

```
m = Model()
for i = 1:2
    @variable(m,string('x',i)>=0)
end
```

I know the `string('x',i)` part is not right but I am not sure how to do this using Julia.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you want an array of `x` variables.

From the [JuMP docs](http://jump.readthedocs.io/en/latest/refvariable.html), you can make an array by using array syntax in your definition.

```
@variable(m, x[1:2] >= 0)
@variable(m, y[1:M,1:N] >= 0)
```

Comment: When I use `@defVar(m, x[1:2] >= 0)` I keep getting an error when I try to solve: `@setObjective(m, Max, 8x1+12x2)
@addConstraint(m, 6x1+8x2<=72)
status=solve(m)' gives error: 
`LoadError: Variable not owned by model present in constraints
while loading In[22], in expression starting on line 5` any ideas?? @IainDunning @Andrew

Comment: Don't use `x1` and `x2`, use `x[1]` and `x[2]`, then it will work.

Comment: Feel free to drop by the julia-opt mailing list if you have questions later!

Answer (score 5):

You can add indices to your variables using `@variable`. The following are all valid in JuMP:

```
m = Model()
@variable(m, x[1:2] >= 0)
@variable(m, boringvariable[1:9,1:9,1:9])
@variable(m, 0 <= pixel_intensity[1:255,1:255] <= 1)
@variable(m, bit_pattern[0:8:63], Bin)
N = 5, M = 10
@variable(m, trucks_dispatched[i=1:N,j=1:M] >= 0, Int)
items = [:sock,:sandal,:boot]
max_stock = [:sock => 10, :sandal => 13, :boot => 5]
@variable(m, 0 <= stock_levels[item=items] <= max_stock[item])
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just add that a 'for' loop in your constraints might look like this:

```
@constraint(m, [i in 1:2], x[i]>=0)
```

where `[i in 1:2]` is your for loop.

Adding to Iain's comment above, better to use `x` as a vector the to be defining individual variables for it - that way you only have the one decision variable.

This is particularly useful when you want to increase the dimensionality of it:
ie `x[i,j]`